What's the movie where a human befriends an alien that talks funny?
I saw this movie somewhen back in the 80's, but recently thought of it and wondered about it. It's not a terribly high-cost movie, but it's not a terribly B-movie either. Just 80's pop I guess?
Two pilots, a human and an alien (crash?) land near one another on a barren planet and become friends. The alien is hurt/old and "pregnant", and in any case dies during "birth" so the human takes it upon himself to raise the child.
In the scene where the human first approaches the seemingly abandoned alien craft, he painfully discovers that it's burglar-proofed by way of electric shock.
Another bit of info is that the alien talks as if he's gurgling, so errverrrythrrring hrrre srrrayrrrs srrroundrrrs weirrrrd. Maybe the alien has some aquatic features? I don't recall, but they are a land-based species.
Any idea what this is?

That is Enemy Mine (1985), with Dennis Quaid as the human and Lou Gossett Jr as the alien. Check out the trailer at the link, it includes many of the plot points you mentioned.


You might want to elaborate in which way this fits the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

What other useful information would need to be included in Drew's answer?  He's right about the movie.  How can a correct answer Not fit the details of the question?

@Drew C, you're spot on, and very quick, too. Was this just on the top of your mind, or how on earth did you pull that rabbit out of your hat? That is, if this is googleable (yes, that's a word ... now) then how?

@KlaymenDK I've seen the movie a few times, so I recognized your description of it immediately. You're absolutely right that, while not a big budget movie, they managed to make a really competent sc-fi story with what they had.
